# How do I define equations containing a summation in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

How do I define the following equation in MATLAB?

```
h(x) = ∑ θ^T*X = θ + θ1*x + θ2*x^2 + ⋯
```

`θ` and `X` are vectors and `T` is traverse function.

Comment: Do you want to define an equation, or evaluate it?

Comment: If you want to define it symbolically, use the MuPad functionnality in the symbolic toolbox.

Comment: How are you squaring a vector? Am I missing something?

Comment: thanks guys,it was exactly the answer below that I was looking for,but that MuPad was also great functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, I believe you are talking about the inner product of two vectors:

[image: equation]

one is using using a summation over all elements (for-loop), the other using vector notation (transposed vector multiplied by another vector)

I say so because the notations used remind me of linear regression: `X` input vector (with bias term `X(0) = 1`), `theta` model parameters (weights), `h` is the hypothesis or output

Example:

```
theta = rand(5,1);
X = rand(5,1);
```

#### for-loop

```
h = 0;
for i=1:length(X)
    h = h + theta(i)*X(i);
end
```

#### matrix-multiplication

```
h = theta'*X;
```

#### dot-product

```
h = dot(theta,X);
```

Answer (score 0):

The notation in the question isn't clear but it looks like X_i = x_i^{i-1}, i=1...N. Then,

```
h = dot(theta,x.^(0:length(x)-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

So simply use

```
h = sum(X*theta')
```